# iframe of a youtube video help in modifying it

Tags: video, iframe, youtube

I don't know if what I want to do is possible
so I am making a website for my final project and I have only learn some CSS and HTML

I am trying to add in my website a video, which I have done successfully.
but now I want to take out from the video everything (the title of the video, the youtube sign and ect)
I just want the video... (I read somewhere it is possible with javascript, is it true?)

So far I put my video in an iframe tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using YouTube videos then they want you to include their logo etc so any techniques to remove will not be approved or supported by YouTube and may break without notice.

However, if all you want to do it support your own video, and it is a simply test system so you are not streaming to many users etc, then you can simply host the video yourself using a simple web server.

There is a simple example using node in this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38915865/334402