# Issue with video streaming on mobile devices using Node.js and Express

Tags: node.js, express, video-streaming, html5-video, node-streams

I'm building a video streaming server using **Node.js** and **Express**. The server works fine when I access it from a desktop browser, but I'm experiencing issues when trying to stream videos on mobile devices. The request is closed abruptly with 0 bytes read, and the video doesn't play.

Here's an overview of my setup:

- **Node.js** version: 16.17.0
- **Express** version: 4.18.2
- **Video format**: mp4 (codec : H264-MPEG-4 AVC)
- Chunk size: the Chunk size that i want to be streamed is 10**6 (**1MB**)

**index.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const app = express();
const port = 3333;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  return res.status(200).sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

app.get('/video', (req, res) => {
  const videoPath = '<VIDEO_PATH>.mp4';
  const videoSize = fs.statSync(videoPath).size;

  const range = req.headers.range;
 if (!range) {
    res.status(400).send('Range header is missing');
  }
  const parts = range.replace(/bytes=/, '').split('-');
  const start = parseInt(parts[0], 10);
  const end = parts[1] ? parseInt(parts[1], 10) : videoSize - 1;
  const chunkSize = end - start + 1;

  res.status(206).header({
    'Content-Range': `bytes ${start}-${end}/${videoSize}`,
    'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
    'Content-Length': chunkSize,
    'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
  });

  fs.createReadStream(videoPath, { start, end }).pipe(res);
});
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port  ${port}`);
});
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Video share</title>
  </head>
  <style>
    body {
      max-width: 720px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      background-color: lightgray;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <video width="420" controls autoplay muted>
      <source src="/video" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've noticed that when I use a smaller chunk size (e.g., 10 ** 6 bytes), the video doesn't play on mobile devices. However, when I set the chunk size to **end - start + 1**, it works, but it loads the entire video file, and it makes only one request.

I've also tried adjusting the chunk size to larger values (e.g., 10 ** 7 bytes), but the problem persists.

**My question is :**

1. What could be causing the issue with streaming videos on mobile devices ?
2. Why does using **"chunkSize = end - start + 1"** allow the video to stream on mobile devices, but not when using smaller chunk sizes?
3. Are there any additional considerations or best practices for video streaming on mobile devices that I might be missing?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. **Thank you!**

Comment: It may be that you have some other goal in mind, but chunked HTTP video streaming is usually driven by the client, e.g. the browser. The protocol is a request response driven - i.e. the browser requests either the whole video, or if the server supports byte ranges, it requests the video in certain ranges, or chunks. These ranges are included in the requests that the browser sends.

Comment: @Mick, yes, I understand what you're saying, and I have already checked if the mobile client (Safari) sends a range header. The header was actually provided. I tried something like, "Hey, if there is a range header, then stream the video in chunks. Otherwise, just serve the entire video." However, the video did not play at all.

Comment: If you just want a solution to stream the videos in the standard way that browsers will request chunked video, then the solution here should work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38915865/334402 . I haven't tested it in a while but the general approach  will be the same now I suspect anyway. The browsers will automatically decide what chunk sizes they want to request and the server should provide them in the response.